# post.add vs post.update vs post.delete in AWS cfn-hup Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

According to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html#cfn-hup-hook-file) for the CloudFormation `cfn-hup` helper script, a cfn-hup hook can have "A comma-delimited list of conditions to detect."  These conditions/triggers can be `post.add`, `post.update`, and/or `post.delete`.  However, there is no description of what these triggers actually mean.  Every example throughout the AWS docs just uses `post.update`, and so far this trigger has been good enough for me, but I'd like to understand what these other triggers are actually used for.  Could someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: No one has any idea on this one?

Comment: Did anyone find an answer for this?

Comment: No, I never did get an answer.  However, I think it's fair to assume that a `post.add` hook is triggered only when the resource in `path` is created by CloudFormation, a `post.update` hook is triggered whenever that resource is updated by CloudFormation, and a `post.delete` hook is triggered only when that resource is deleted by CloudFormation.  Don't quote me on that, as I never did any testing on this, but that would make the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of the code for update_hooks.py from a version of the cfn scripts from 2019 that can be found at https://pypi.org/project/aws-cfn-bootstrap/:

```
 def _process_hook(self, hook, metadata):
    try:
        new_data = self._retrieve_path_data(hook.path)
    except InFlightStatusError:
        return

    old_data = self._jsonConverter.deserialize(metadata.get(hook.name + "|" + hook.path, None))

    if 'post.add' in hook.triggers and not old_data and new_data:
        log.info("Previous state not found; action for %s will be run", hook.name)
    elif 'post.remove' in hook.triggers and old_data and not new_data:
        log.info('Path %s was removed; action for %s will be run', hook.path, hook.name)
    elif 'post.update' in hook.triggers and old_data and new_data and old_data != new_data:
        log.info("Data has changed from previous state; action for %s will be run", hook.name)
    else:
        log.debug("No change in path %s for hook %s", hook.path, hook.name)
        metadata[hook.name + "|" + hook.path] = self._jsonConverter.serialize(new_data)
        JsonFileManager.write(self.dir, 'metadata_db.json', metadata)
        return
```

So, the triggers apply to the path of the metadata specified in the hook spec, which can indicate a node *within* the Metadata block, not just the whole block.

- post.add: path node didn't exist before and now does
- post.remove path node did exist before and now doesn't
- post.update path node existed before and still exists, but its contents have changed

In a comment earlier, someone wisely speculated exactly this, but here's the code that proves that that is so.

Answer (score -1):

post.add, post.update, and/or post.delete  are trigger  used in cfn-hup

Simple words : These are the trigger point looking for changes in the cfn stack template and based on the trigger some action to be performed.

**More details :**

The cfn-hup helper is a daemon that detects changes in resource metadata and runs user-specified actions when a change is detected

This helper is supported with 2 files :

/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf
/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf

**/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf**

This contains the configurtaion related to cfn-hup with details including stack name to monitor and how frequent it should monitor.

Eg:

```
    [main]
    stack=Test-Cfn-Stack-Name
    region=${AWS::Region}
    interval=1   ### every one minute it will monitor the stack for changes 
    verbose=true
```

In this example, cfn-hup daemon will monitor the cfn stack from the ec2 instance every 1 min. The logs of this activity are located in /var/log/cfn-hup.log. If any changes are detected "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf" will take control here for next actions.

**/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf**

In this file it has information about which resource should be monitored in the above mentioned cfn stack and if any changes are detected in the resource metadata like addition, deletion or update then perform the action mentioned in the actions filed.

Eg :

```
[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
triggers=post.add,post.update
ath=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchConfig --configsets wordpress_install --region ${AWS::Region}
runas=root
```

In this example, cfn-hup daemon will send the trigger to this file saying that cfn stack was updated with the template which modifications in the LaunchConfig resource`s metadata, so please run the command mentioned in the action field.

This command in the action feild will run the configsets mentioned in the LaunchConfig on the  ec2 instance.